# RowSource can not find data

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently writing a jumble of excel code to track a number, items and dates and staff members.
I got to a point where I do a search using a cbobox and variant of letters or names to gather data and place it into a list box showing headers and columns

via the Name Manager i have set up: `=OFFSET(NEW_IBO_Tracker!$AA$9,0,0,COUNTA(NEW_IBO_Tracker!$AA$9:$AA$9000),15)`.
I have set up a basic code to test this and it works. It searches the main data, gathers the (selected search variable eg "an"), then makes a copy of all the names that contain "an" places this into the offset location.

The issue that I am having is that the main code is NOT doing the above

```
Private Sub cmdGetData_Click()
Dim Crit As Range
Dim FindMe As Range
Dim DataSH As Worksheet
Set DataSH = Sheet4
On Error GoTo errHandler:


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'///////////////////////////////////////////
'if header is selected add the criteria
If Me.cboHeader.Value <> "All_Columns" Then
    If Me.txtSearch = "" Then
        DataSH.Range("Y9") = ""
    Else
        DataSH.Range("Y9") = "*" & Me.txtSearch.Value & "*"
    End If
End If
'///////////////////////////////////////////
'If all columns is selected
If Me.cboHeader.Value = "All_Columns" Then
    'find the value in the column
    Set FindMe = DataSH.Range("B9:O100000").Find(What:=txtSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    'variable for criteria header
    Set Crit = DataSH.Cells(8, FindMe.Column)
    'if no criteria is added to the search
    If Me.txtSearch = "" Then
        DataSH.Range("Y9") = ""
        DataSH.Range("Y8") = ""
    Else
        'add values from the search
        DataSH.Range("Y8") = Crit
        If Crit = "ID" Then
            DataSH.Range("Y9") = Me.txtSearch.Value
        Else
            DataSH.Range("Y9") = "*" & Me.txtSearch.Value & "*"
        End If
        'show in the userform the header that is added
        Me.txtAllColumn = DataSH.Range("Y8").Value
    End If
End If
'/////////////////////////////////////////
'unprotect all sheets
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Unprotect_All
'Filter the data
DataSH.Range("B8").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CriteriaRange:=Range("NEW_IBO_Tracker!$Y$8:$Y$9"), CopyToRange:=Range("NEW_IBO_Tracker!$AA$8:$AO$8"), _
Unique:=False
'add the dynamic data to the listbox
lstData.RowSource = DataSH.Range("outdata").Address(external:=True)     
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Protect_All
'error handler
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Protect all sheets
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Protect_All
'If error occurs then show me exactly where the error occurs
MsgBox "No match found for: " & txtSearch.Text
'clear the listbox if no match is found
Me.lstData.RowSource = ""
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I am willing to send the workbook if anyone thinks it would be easier. I have spent about a week trying to get this little bit to work and it's driving me insane OHH YAY!!
Thanks heaps in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: from the code supplied, can the reason for not working be in there. If not what would be the best way to find out why its not doing what it is meant to do

Comment: @Drag00n You need to be more specific about what your current code is doing. What is the current behavior, and what is the expected result? But don't just say "It's supposed to do this, but right now it doesn't do this". That tells us nothing. Are you getting an error message??

Comment: Using a userform, i can add staff into a small database, then with the same userform. I am able to do a search, via 2 options. 1 is with a combobox that selects the column header. the other option is with the input of part of all of a name. This then copies all relevant data and pastes it to ("AA9:AO9") or ("AA9:AO15") depending on the number of rows copied. then it shows this data that has just been pasted into AA9 via a listbox in the userform

Comment: I think that I have narrowed it down to the adding the dynamic data to the listbox - 
    `lstData.RowSource = DataSH.Range("outdata").Address(external:=true)`
Would this cause the AdvancedFilter to not actually find the data?

Comment: @dwirony does the above two comments help?

Comment: @Drag00n I'm sorry, I'm still having a hard time following what your code is doing. I would suggest deleting and re-posting your question with the specifics that you've put in these comments.